# How much data is exchanged between Microsoft Servers and Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, cloud

My internet is capped, so I need to make sure my systems are not needlessly sending and receiving data.

How do I control and limit the amount of data Windows 8.1 sends and receives as part of its base services and systems?

Bonus: Does anybody know how much data communication occurs between a default installation of Windows 8.1 and Microsoft servers?

Comment: How do you handle it with your current OS?  It's actually easier in Windows 8.1 to handle metered connection than ever before

Comment: While as it is phrased it is broad, the easily seen question is: What steps to take to minimize network usage by the base OS in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Paranoid.

For all intents and purposes, no data is being sent to or from Microsoft from Windows 8.1.  If you open the Resource Monitor - click start and type `resource monitor` - and click on Network, you will see all the applications that are using the network.  You should see no MS applications using the network.  Obviously this isnt true 100% of the time, applications like Skype, IE, SkyDrive, etc will occassionally use network resources.

To save data, close any applications are background apps that use the Internet until necessary.

Comment: Error reports, if his account is synced, Microsoft Update, all these are sending or receiving data from MS. With Update, this can be quite a bit even.

Comment: Don't forget the "Internet connection"-status, which accesses  dns.msftncsi.com (see [this blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/). Doesn't add much to your quota, but Bill surely knows when you turn on your computer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a handy page for Metered Connections and how to configure Windows to treat them nicely: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/metered-internet-connections-frequently-asked-questions

If you're on a wired connection it isn't as easy to set, but there are still things you can do.

But if you're on a wireless you can set the connection to Metered, and this will tell your computer to only download priority updates, it will disable apps from updating automatically, it will disable some Live Tiles (weather data and the like), and it will disable automatic offline file sync.

**How do I set a Metered Connection?**

1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)
2. Tap or click Network, and then tap or click Connections.
3. Tap or click the connection you want to change, and then, under Data usage, turn Set as a metered connection on or off.